# Qt3D QML Read FBO

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I would like to know if it's possible to read data from a FBO in Qt3D? I have 2 render passes, one is saved in a texture, the other renders on the screen. I want to read pixels from the texture but so far I haven't had any luck.

Would appreciate any input!

Edit: Here's some code of the RenderSettings object from the shadow map example. What I want to do is read a certain position of the shadowmapTexture after the pass. For example, after a mouse click in a certain x,y position, read the data of the Texture2D on that same x,y pos.

```
property alias viewCamera: viewCameraSelector.camera
property alias lightCamera: lightCameraSelector.camera
readonly property Texture2D shadowTexture: depthTexture

activeFrameGraph: Viewport {
    normalizedRect: Qt.rect(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    RenderSurfaceSelector {
        RenderPassFilter {
            matchAny: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "shadowmap" } ]

           RenderTargetSelector {
                target: RenderTarget {
                    attachments: [
                        RenderTargetOutput {
                            objectName: "depth"
                            attachmentPoint: RenderTargetOutput.Depth
                            texture: Texture2D {
                                id: depthTexture
                                width: 1024
                                height: 1024
                                format: Texture.DepthFormat
                                generateMipMaps: false
                                magnificationFilter: Texture.Linear
                                minificationFilter: Texture.Linear
                                wrapMode {
                                    x: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                                    y: WrapMode.ClampToEdge
                                }
                                comparisonFunction: Texture.CompareLessEqual
                                comparisonMode: Texture.CompareRefToTexture
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }

                ClearBuffers {
                    buffers: ClearBuffers.DepthBuffer

                    CameraSelector {
                        id: lightCameraSelector
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        RenderPassFilter {
            matchAny: [ FilterKey { name: "pass"; value: "forward" } ]

            ClearBuffers {
                clearColor: Qt.rgba(0.0, 0.4, 0.7, 1.0)
                buffers: ClearBuffers.ColorDepthBuffer

                CameraSelector {
                    id: viewCameraSelector
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code describing the issue?

Comment: I've added some code and a more detailed description of what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

use [RayCaster](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-raycaster.html) and [ScreenRayCaster](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-screenraycaster.html)
it gives you the local position and world position and screen x , y
see [this site](https://www.kdab.com/new-in-qt-3d-5-11-generalized-ray-casting/)  from kdab and its example

```
RenderSettings{
    
    //all components that you need like viewport , InputSettings ,...
    
    ScreenRayCaster {
        id: screenRayCaster
        
        onHitsChanged: printHits("Screen hits", hits)
    }
}

MouseHandler {
    id: mouseHandler
    sourceDevice:  MouseDevice {}
    onReleased: { screenRayCaster.trigger(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)) }
}

function printHits(desc, hits) {
    console.log(desc, hits.length)
    for (var i=0; i<hits.length; i++) {
        console.log("  " + hits[i].entity.objectName, hits[i].distance,
                    hits[i].worldIntersection.x, hits[i].worldIntersection.y, hits[i].worldIntersection.z)
    }
}
```